# ¿Cómo puedo extraer horas para un gráfico en ggplot?

Tags: r, date, rstudio, timeseries, ggplot

Utilicé los siguientes datos:

| Date | Sector | CH4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17/12/22 14:00 | Capuli | 4.215823529 |
| 17/12/22 16:00 | Capuli | 1.978485714 |
| 18/12/22 12:00 | Capuli | 2.674290323 |
| 18/12/22 14:00 | Capuli | 2.376083333 |
| 18/12/22 16:00 | Capuli | 4.618833333 |
| 18/12/22 18:00 | Capuli | 4.140970455 |
| 19/12/22 12:00 | Capuli | 4.1885 |
| 19/12/22 18:00 | Capuli | 4.08795 |
| 20/12/22 08:00 | Capuli | 2.803439171 |
| 20/12/22 10:00 | Capuli | 4.83355 |
| 20/12/22 12:00 | Capuli | 4.250918182 |
| 20/12/22 14:00 | Capuli | 4.8715 |
| 20/12/22 16:00 | Capuli | 5.6434 |
| 21/12/22 08:00 | Capuli | 7.192572727 |
| 21/12/22 10:00 | Capuli | 7.366627273 |
| 21/12/22 14:00 | Capuli | 6.973924138 |
| 21/12/22 16:00 | Capuli | 7.211654545 |
| 22/12/22 08:00 | Capuli | 4.23723913 |
| 22/12/22 10:00 | Capuli | 1.864188172 |
| 22/12/22 12:00 | Capuli | 7.283677778 |
| 22/12/22 14:00 | Capuli | 6.664268539 |
| 22/12/22 16:00 | Capuli | 1.655128125 |
| 17/1/23 12:00 | Capuli | 0.61686747 |
| 17/1/23 14:00 | Capuli | 0.189431818 |
| 17/1/23 16:00 | Capuli | 0.144 |
| 18/1/23 10:00 | Capuli | 1.505540541 |
| 18/1/23 12:00 | Capuli | 1.134382022 |
| 18/1/23 14:00 | Capuli | 1.152988506 |
| 18/1/23 16:00 | Capuli | 0.816271186 |
| 19/1/23 16:00 | Capuli | 1.703 |
| 23/12/22 10:00 | Punzara | 1.1749 |
| 23/12/22 12:00 | Punzara | 1.226269231 |
| 13/1/23 10:00 | Punzara | 1.620357143 |
| 13/1/23 12:00 | Punzara | 1.533863636 |
| 13/1/23 14:00 | Punzara | 1.496582278 |
| 13/1/23 16:00 | Punzara | 0.729692308 |
| 14/1/23 10:00 | Punzara | 0.137931034 |
| 14/1/23 12:00 | Punzara | 0.151363636 |
| 14/1/23 14:00 | Punzara | 0.2375 |
| 14/1/23 16:00 | Punzara | 0.146521739 |
| 15/1/23 10:00 | Punzara | 0.108461538 |
| 15/1/23 12:00 | Punzara | 0.124038462 |
| 15/1/23 14:00 | Punzara | 0.0921875 |
| 15/1/23 16:00 | Punzara | 0.118846154 |

la estructura de datos es la siguiente:

| * str(df1) |  |
| --- | --- |
| $'data.frame':44 obs. of 12 variables: |  |
| $ Date : POSIXct, format: "0022-12-17 14:00:00" ... |  |
| $ Sector : chr "Capuli" "Capuli" "Capuli" "Capuli" ... |  |
| $ CH4 : num 4.221.98 2.67 2.38 4.62 ... |  |
| $ CO2 : num 255 224 449 430 356 ... |  |
| $ N2O : num 0.132 0.148 0.184 0.203 0.211 ... |  |
| $ Humedad : num 57.7 57 80.6 82.4 88.5 ... |  |
| $ Temperatura: num 21.6 21.1 22.3 22.1 19.1 ... |  |
| $ MO : num 8.11 8.11 8.11 8.11 8.11 8.11 ... |  |
| $ Dr : num 2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3 ... |  |
| $ Po : num 43.5 43.5 43.5 43.5 43.5 ... |  |
| $ N : num 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.41 0.41 ...* |  |

El siguiente es el código usado para la gráfica:

```
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = CH4, color = Sector)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous()+
  labs(title="Emisiones de GEI intervalo 2H",hjust = 0.5,
       subtitle = "Flujos de suelos ganaderos en ppm",
       tag = "A",
       caption="Fuente: Elaboración propia 2023") +
  xlab("Horas") +
  ylab("Concentración (ppm)")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~Sector)
```

La gráfica a continuación no muestra los datos en horas. Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es que no tienes horas, tienes fechas/horas.  Si quieres extraer horas no veo mucho sentido  usar un `geom_line` ¿Qué es exactamente lo que buscas?

Comment: Gracias Patricio como siempre por la ayuda; en Date está la fecha y hora 17/12/22 14:00, solamente necesito que se muestre en el eje x 14:00, 16h00 etc y lo que me sale en la gráfica es el mes y día

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que que entiendo es que deseas agrupar observaciones por hora, el tema es que en esta caso, tienes más de una observación por hora, pero si queremos que se corresponda con un punto habría que sumarizar las observaciones, por ejemplo usando la media:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(hora = format(Date, format = "%H:%M")) %>% 
  group_by(Sector, hora) %>% 
  summarise(CH4 = mean(CH4)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = CH4, color = Sector, group = Sector)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous()+
  labs(title="Emisiones promedio de GEI intervalo 2H",hjust = 0.5,
       subtitle = "Flujos de suelos ganaderos en ppm",
       tag = "A",
       caption="Fuente: Elaboración propia 2023") +
  xlab("Horas") +
  ylab("Concentración (ppm)")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~Sector)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentarios:

- Siempre que `Date` sea una fecha y no una cadena, con  `mutate(hora = format(Date, format = "%H:%M"))` extraemos solo hora y minutos
- Con `group_by(Sector, hora) %>% summarise(CH4 = mean(CH4))` agrupamos las distintas fechas por la hora y promediamos el valor de `CH4`
- Hay que agregar la estética `group`: `ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = CH4, color = Sector, group = Sector))` necesaria para generar la curva.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias Patricio por la ayuda! Saludos